# When can we write evolving curves as curves over a fixed curve?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $\gamma(t)$ for each $t$ is a curve. We may write $$\gamma(t)(s) = \gamma_0(s) + d(t,s)N(s)$$
where $\gamma_0$ is some fixed curve, $N$ is the unit normal vector and $d$ is a distance from $\gamma_0$ to the curve $\gamma(t)$.

Under what conditions can this be done? I vaguely recall we need $\gamma_0$ to be Lipschitz, but don't know why or how. And for what $t$ can be this done? Appreciate any references or explanation.

Thanks

Comment: There is not a clear question here. "We may write ..." Of course you can always *write* that. You've written a definition down, so I don't see a reason for there to be a problem unless there are some more conditions going on (also, what is $N(s)$?).

Comment: @Matt Sorry, $N$ is the unit normal vector. My question is, given $\gamma(t)$ and $\gamma_0$, what are the conditions under which that equation I wrote down makes sense? That may be unclear but I don't have any more details I'm afraid. I just heard about it and want to know more.

Comment: One can always make a [parallel curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelCurves.html) from a given curve...